# How Can I update a var in the AlertDialog Widget?

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog, setstate

I need to update the percentage var inside the AlertDialog, I know that you can't update anything inside the showDialog() which I am using here because it is built in another Widget tree, but worth asking, it would really be very helpful.
Thanks in advance. :)

**Update**

The uploadTask listener redo the function until sth like Navigator pushes to a different screen.

**My Code**

```
Future storageupload() async {
      await checkInternet();
      try {
        if (controller == null) {
          dialog('Error', 'Please Provide A Video Name', () => {});
        } else {
          StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child("Khatma 1")
              .child("Videos")
              .child(controller.text != null ? controller.text : "");
          StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
              File(Variables.lastVideoPath),
              StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
          uploadTask.events.listen((event) {
            if (uploadTask.isComplete) {
              AwesomeDialog(
                context: context,
                headerAnimationLoop: false,
                dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
                animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
                title: 'Uploaded',
                desc: 'Your Video Was Successfully Uploaded !',
                btnOkOnPress: () => {print('success')},
              )..show();
            } else {
              setState(() {
                percentage = event.snapshot.bytesTransferred /
                    event.snapshot.totalByteCount *
                    100;
              });
            }
          });
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Uploading'),
                content: Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text('Uploading .... Please Be Patient'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    Text(percentage.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

**code**

```
return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, void function) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Uploading'),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Uploading .... Please Be Patient'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  Text(percentage.toString()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222906/discussion-on-question-by-flutterdeveloper11-how-can-i-update-a-var-in-the-alert).

Answer (score 0):

all dialogs are StateLess widgets.... so u can not call setstate to update their data to show on the UI. If u want to do that then u can wrap the dialog inside a [StatefullBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) . which will allow you to call setState.

Comment: it doesn't build at all.